# Proper way to wait N cycles in ARM Cortex-M4

Tags: c, arm, assembly, texas-instruments, cortex-m4

After enabling a clock for a certain port you have to wait 4 cycles for the clock to finish initializing. How can one wait for N cycles the proper way?

In my code I used this:

```
__asm("nop");
__asm("nop");
__asm("nop");
__asm("nop");
```

After which uKeil IDE seem to stop complaining.

Comment: Alternatively you wait loop on the clock status register. In case it takes longer to initialize than expected (pll fault or power on brownout/crystal startup)

Comment: NOPs are bad idea. "NOP does nothing. NOP is not necessarily a time-consuming NOP. The processor might remove it from the pipeline before it reaches the execution stage.

Use NOP for padding, for example to place the following instruction on a 64-bit boundary." which is quoted from  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDJJGFB.html

Comment: these mcus are pipeline based and not deterministic, so unlike the old days you cant just insert instructions and assume they take some amount of time.  you can tune some code in a certain situation sure, but you have to tune it you cant just count instructions.  The correct way to consume a specific amount of time is to use a timer (and then there is the non-deterministic latency and handler code that goes with it but it is more predictable and reliable than hand counting instructions).

Comment: if you just want to kill some time in a simple way and not have the compiler get in your way, voltatile works, I prefer a dummy function, in some asm place the instruction bx lr.  then make a loop for(i=0;i<100;i++) dummy(i);  and the compiler cannot optimize that loop away.

Answer (score 2):

This is one method from [here](http://embedded-systems-drivers-launchpad.blogspot.com/2014/03/stellaristiva-c-series-cortex-m4123g.html):

```
 volatile unsigned long delay;

 SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= 0x00000010;   // 1) activate clock for Port E
 delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;         //    allow time for clock to stabilize
```

You could also set up us the clock(s) and go do something else for a few cycles (initialize some stuff) but that's a potential bug in the future.

---

Edit: The dummy line compiles to:

```
  400286:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
  400288:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]
```

On the Cortex M4

> ldr is 2 cycles
>
> str is 2 cycles

See [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/CHDDIGAC.html) for M4 cycle counts.

The *volatile* keyword keeps the ldr and str instructions from being combined, as I understand it.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: I've seen this before, but it's very vague to me. How do I know if a dummy assignment will take at least 4 cycles?

Comment: @Daveel ; I think "memory barriers" and "volatile" will give you the answer